# Swift why doesn't my generator protocol extension work?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift-protocols

I think my cognition for Swift types/protocols/generics has overflowed. I've been using the pattern of extending "an input stream bytes" by doing something like:

```
extension GeneratorType where Element == UInt8 {
    func foobar()  {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's worked in the past for simple stuff. And today I was playing with the following:

```
protocol Unpackable {
    static func unpack(inout input:IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>) -> Self
}

extension UInt8:Unpackable {
    static func unpack(inout input:IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>) -> UInt8 {
        return input.next()!
    }
}

extension UInt16:Unpackable {
    static func unpack(inout input:IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>) -> UInt16 {
        return UInt16(input.next()!) | (UInt16(input.next()!) << 8)
    }
}
```

Works fine. But if I try to put the two together with something like

```
extension GeneratorType where Element == UInt8 {
    func unpackAll() -> (UInt8, UInt16) {
        return (UInt8.unpack(&self), UInt16.unpack(&self))
}
```

then I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Self' to expected argument type 'IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>'
```

Doesn't an IndexingGenerator conform to GeneratorType? Is its Element not UInt8? Is the error in using IndexingGenerator? I can't specify the argument types as GeneratorType (though I'd really like to be able to).

I'm still waiting for the light bulb to flicker on for Swift types. Some days I really like the language. Other days, I feel like I'm yelling at my dog trying to get him to come, and he just stares at me without moving, then turns and chases down the street anyway.

Comment: "Doesn't an IndexingGenerator conform to GeneratorType" Yes but not every GeneratorType is an IndexingGenerator.

Comment: I made the arguments `IndexingGenerator<[UInt8]>` only because I couldn't figure out how to do it more generically. I honestly don't care that it's an IndexingGenerator. I would be fine with a Generator of any type, as long as it produced UInt8's. Is there a way to have an argument that is a Protocol of appropriate specification?

Comment: Is the trick to declare a *new* protocol that conforms to `GeneratorType` and somehow restrains conforming types to have elements of a `UInt8` ?

Comment: Could the solution have something to do with AnyGenerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension GeneratorType where Element == UInt8 {
    func unpackAll() -> (UInt8, UInt16)? {
        guard let _self = self as? IndexingGenerator<[Element]> else { return nil }
        var vSelf = _self
        return (UInt8.unpack(&vSelf), UInt16.unpack(&vSelf))
    }
}
```

---

Update:

```
protocol Unpackable {
    static func unpack<T : GeneratorType where T.Element == UInt8>(inout input:T) -> Self
}

extension UInt8: Unpackable {
    static func unpack<T : GeneratorType where T.Element == UInt8>(inout input: T) -> UInt8 {
        return input.next()!
    }
}

extension UInt16: Unpackable {
    static func unpack<T : GeneratorType where T.Element == UInt8>(inout input: T) -> UInt16 {
        return UInt16(input.next()!) | (UInt16(input.next()!) << 8)
    }
}

extension GeneratorType where Element == UInt8 {
    mutating func unpackAll() -> (UInt8, UInt16) {
        return (UInt8.unpack(&self), UInt16.unpack(&self))
    }
}
```

Comment: Could say `guard var vSelf` and be one line shorter :)

Comment: @matt LOL. Honestly, I never use `var` with `guard` and I assume I can't do it! How stupid I am...Thanks for the tip.

Comment: This forces me to wrap the return type as an optional. Not the end of the world, but not what I was looking for. I'm trying to close the gap between having to use a Protocol to extend a Generic, but having to pass a Generic as the type of an argument.

Comment: @TravisGriggs Although I still can not figure out what exactly you want, check out my update see if this makes sense?

Comment: YES! That's what I was looking for I think. Basically, how do I type the argument as the same refined protocol I had extended. So that it didn't fight me when intermixing them.